# width "matching" on css custom dropdown

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to style [this custom dropdown menu](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/10/04/custom-drop-down-list-styling/)

But the part that drops down is always slightly narrower (1px on each side) than the "headline" part of the dropdown.

When I change width here,

```
.wrapper-dropdown-1 {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

nothing seems to happen. How can I adjust this so the part that drops down is the same width as the top part? Where is this being controlled at? In the [demo](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CustomDropDownListStyling/), the widths seem to align perfectly, and I cannot understand how I've changed the style to affect it.

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/uvuwuw/4/edit)

Comment: Why do you link to a comment page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you adding or removing borders from one of the elements? If it's one px on each side that seems like the likely cause.

You can/should either match the borders or, if you are okay losing some cross-browser compatibility, you could use [box-sizing](http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/):

`box-sizing: padding-box`
(with vendor prefixes for now, e.g. `-webkit-box-sizing: padding-box`).

Another (hacky) way to do it would be to set the dropdown's `margin-left` and `margin-right` to `-1px` or, equivalently, from your JSBin, change `left`/`right` to `-1px`:

```
.wrapper-dropdown-1 .dropdown {
     /* Size & position */
     position: absolute;
     top: 100%;
     left: -1px;
     right: -1px;

      /* ... */
```

}

Comment: I've tried playing with the borders, and that seems not to affect the width issue. To which element should I apply the `box-sizing:padding box`? Thanks!

Comment: See my edit, now that I've seen your JSBin I'd go with the last suggestion (left/right)